# Xubuntu Nvidia drivers are messed up?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu

I just installed this Xubuntu, and everytime I login to my account it just shows the desktop, just the wallpaper and mouse, and stays frozen. All I can use is Firefox.

When I signed into xfce with the open source driver it did however it would work.

How do I make it work with my nvidia driver? I had no problems on Linux Mint or Debian. I've tried many guides.
I couldn't use the 19 version of Xubuntu, I had to use the 18 versions one.
I currently have a nitro 5, i5 8300k, gtx 1050. Is it possible I can resort back to the open source driver? Or to make the gtx 1050 driver work?

Comment: Most likely you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: disabled for ages. Isnt the issue.